# Operators in Java

Tags: java, operators

I am studying operators in Java and I have a problem that I can't solve.

```
    public static boolean first(){
       System.out.println("first");
       return true;
   }
   public static boolean second(){
       System.out.println("second");
       return true;
   }
   public static boolean third(){
       System.out.println("third");
       return true;
   }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       if(first() && second() | third()){
           //Do something
       }
    }
```

The output is "first second third". I think it shoud be "second third first" because | is greater than &&. I don't know where is my mistake but obviously there is one.

Comment: type `if(first() && second() || third()){`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't confuse operator precedence with *evaluation order*. [Java always evaluates expressions left-to-right](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7):

> The Java programming language guarantees that the operands of operators appear to be evaluated in a specific evaluation order, namely, from left to right.

So, the output is:

```
first
second
third
```

because of the order that the method calls are in the expression:

```
first() && second() | third()
```

The actual operators used (`&&`, `|` or `||`) is irrelevant to the order. A different choice of operators might result in some lines not being printed, but those that are printed will be in this order.

Answer (score 1):

`first() && second() | third()` is evaluated as `first() && (second() | third())` due to *operator precedence*. And evaluation takes place from left to right, so `first()` is evaluated first, followed by `(second() | third())`. In evaluating this latter term, *both* arguments are evaluated (again starting from the left), since `first()` is `true`, and there is *no* short-circuiting for the `|` operator.

**Did you mean to use a single `|`?**

The less idiosyncratic `first() && second() || third()` is evaluated as `(first() && second()) || third()`. `first()` and `second()` are both evaluated in this instance (and in that order) since `first()` returns `true`. Since `second()` also returns `true`, `third()` would *not* be evaluated.

Comment: I think that evaluation order is more important than precedence or short-circuiting here. OP expects (and sees) all three expressions evaluated; it seems to be the evaluation order which they are not expecting.